# indefinite retry on exception in apache beam dataflow job

Tags: apache-beam

I am running a streaming pipeline created with apache beam SDK 2.39 on GCP as a dataflow job. Basically i read from PubSub and write to PubSub, doing some aggregations windowed by wall time clock.

I am facing a problem when a runtime exception is thrown from one of my ParDo operations
(the cause of runtime exception is that one of input elements from PubSub is "invalid": has a property being null but code assumes it is non-null). What i observe:

- beam starts to indefinitely retry a failure element (actually an aggregated event)
- new input elements (coming to input PubSub) are aggregated correctly
- a number of log messages in GCP console is increasing with each reprocessing of problematic aggregated event
- if i kill my beam job and start it again, all problems are gone and offending input element is not processed again, which suggests to me that input elements are acknowledged as soon as they are read by apache beam.

I am looking for a general way to handle this case:
i would like to "retry" a problematic element a configured number of times (to cover some transient problems as in one of my ParDo i am accessing BigQuery) but after a number of retries i would simply like to log the problem and ignore offending element - i do not care that output messages will be out-of-order.

Can it be done somehow in Apache Beam? I know i could potentially wrap all my ParDo logic within try/catch block, but:

- how do i know if the element is processed for the first time or it's retried
- i would need to wrap all ParDo in this kind of logic (can fallback to some TemplateMethod pattern)
  Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you take a look at try/catch and [beam.retry](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.4.0/apache_beam.utils.retry.html#apache_beam.utils.retry.with_exponential_backoff)?

Comment: It is  "For internal use only" - which is not the problem  but this module is mostly about "common code" to call remote services ...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to put a try/catch block in your DoFn's process method (possibly with a for loop to retry a fixed number of times). You can then emit the persistently-failing message to a [distinct output](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#multiple-outputs-dofn), if you want to do something else with it (e.g. count them or record them for future inspection). This pattern (modulo the retry, thought that might be a worthwhile feature to add) is generally called the "dead letter" pattern and is available in Python via [ParDo(...).with_exception_handling(...)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.39.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.ParDo.with_exception_handling).

Comment: It would work, but it is definitely not general solution... i know about try/catch and then producing side output with tags but as soon as these are used the whole pipeline looses composability. And then you would need to pollute all of your ParDo with try/catch/retry...

Comment: You are correct--you have to wrap every problematic operation in try...catch to do anything other than fail repeatedly. If this is a common pattern you could perhaps somewhat automate it with a decorator of some sort.